# REST Update Recipient Email using PUT Method

Tags: api, rest, docusignapi

I am new to REST and keep getting the Bad Request 400 Response with the code below:

I have the standard baseURL and authenticateStr from the other sample...

_recipientID, pNewEmail, pNewName and pNewRoutingOrder are passed in as parameters to the procedures.

```
            string envDef = "<envelopeDefinition xmlns=\"http://www.docusign.com/restapi\">" +
                                "<signers>" +
                                    "<signer>" +
                                            "<recipientId>" + _recipientId + "</recipientId>" +
                                            "<email>" + pNewEmail + "</email>" +
                                            "<name>" + pNewName + "</name>" +
                                            "<routingOrder>" + pNewRoutingOrder + "</routingOrder>" +
                                    "</signer>" +
                                "</signers>" +
                            "</envelopeDefinition>"; 

        url = baseURL + "/envelopes/" + pEnvelopeID + "/recipients";
        request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.Headers.Add("X-DocuSign-Authentication", authenticateStr);
        request.ContentType = "application/xml";
        request.Accept = "application/xml";
        request.ContentLength = envDef.Length;
        request.Method = "PUT";
        // write the body of the request
        byte[] body = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(envDef);
        Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        dataStream.Write(body, 0, envDef.Length);
        dataStream.Close();
        // read the response
        webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        sr.Close();

        responseText = "";
        sr = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream());
        responseText = sr.ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: can you share what the error string is (besides the error code?)?  Also if you have the envelope definition that'd be helpful too.  It could very well be that how your envelope is before you make that call affects what the system sees as valid and invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Ok just figured out how to do this.  Here's an XML request body that can be used to update the email and name of a recipient, for instance.  I just verified that this works!

```
<recipients xmlns="http://www.docusign.com/restapi">
   <signers>
      <signer>
         <recipientId>1</recipientId>
         <email>email@docusign.com</email>
         <name>Joe Mama</name>
      </signer>
   </signers>
</recipients>
```